# iOS : How to upload multiple images to server using multipart using alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have to upload multiple images to the server through alamofire. I am able to get the images in the form of array, convert them to data but when i upload them to the server only first image is appearing.
I am sharing my code please help.

i am getting image array of this type

> image array== [<UIImage:0x2804cb210 anonymous {1170, 2532}
> renderingMode=automatic(original)>, <UIImage:0x2804f03f0 anonymous
> {1170, 2532} renderingMode=automatic(original)>]

and when i convert it to data from the code i got this response

```
print("image array==", self.images)
        
        self.photoImageData = self.images.compactMap {  $0.pngData() }
        print("====", photoImageData)
```

> ==== [4074684 bytes, 1353198 bytes]

here is my function

```
func hitPostAPIWithprofileImageArray(urlString: String, params: [String: String],imageData: [Data],imageKey: String, completionHandler:@escaping (_ result: [String: Any], _ errorC : Error?) -> Void)
    {
        print("params-> ",params)
        let openUrl : URL
        openUrl = URL(string: baseURL + urlString)!
        print("params-> ",openUrl)
        Alamofire.upload(
            multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
                for imageData in imageData {
                    multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: imageKey, fileName: "user.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
                }
                for (key, value) in params {
                    multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
                }
            },
            to: openUrl,
            encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                switch encodingResult {
                case .success(let upload, _, _):
                    upload.responseJSON { response in
                        debugPrint(response)
                        do{
                            let result = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [String:Any]
                            print(result)
                            let errorC = Error.self
                            completionHandler(result,errorC as? Error)
                        }catch{
                            if let err = response.error {
                                completionHandler(self.resultG,err as? Error);                                return
                            }
                        }                    }
                    upload.uploadProgress(queue: DispatchQueue(label: "uploadQueue"), closure: { (progress) in
                    })
                case .failure(let encodingError):
                    print(encodingError)
                    completionHandler(self.resultG,encodingError as? Error)
                }
            }
        )
    }
```

Comment: You are sending multiple images, but they are all under the same `imageKey` name? What's in `params`? Could it be info for each images?

Comment: Unrelated but: `value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!` can be simplified into `Data(value.utf8)` (no force unwrap & shorter). `let result = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [String:Any]`You don't need `allowFragments` here, since you expect a `Dictionary`. Allso, the output should be the same as `response.value` or `response` (I don't rememberr). Since you used completion `response.JSON`, it should already have called internally `JSONSerialization`. You are doing it twice.

Comment: @Larme i am using the param "media" in which i am posting images. Please help me to resolve this

Comment: I'd tend to say, don't use the same `withName: imageKey, fileName: "user.jpg"` for each photos. Use `"\(imageKey)\(i)"` & "user\(i).jpg", where is the for loop increment.

Comment: can you please share some code i really need help as i am stuck in it and unable to resolve

Comment: `for (index,imageData) in imageData.enumerated() { multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: \(imageKey)\(index)", fileName: "user\(index).jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg") }`

Comment: i tried this but it is not working now image is not appearing previously first image was appearing. how to convert this [4074684 bytes, 1353198 bytes] to [{}, {}] format

Comment: "how to convert this [4074684 bytes, 1353198 bytes] to [{}, {}] format" This doesn't make sense, you are sending raw data, not embedding images into JSON. Also, again what's "media"? Is there any info related to the images there?

Comment: media is the param name/key in which i am posting imagedata as.   WebServiceHelper.sharedInstanceAPI.hitPostAPIWithprofileImageArray(urlString: KeyConstant.APIcreate_post, params: ["user_id":self.useridStr, "app_mode" : "iOS"], imageData: photoImageData, imageKey: "media", completionHandler: { (result: [String:Any], err:Error?) in
                print(result)

Comment: Can you post multiple images? What's the API doc saying you should format them? Does the `fileName` only be different? `for (index,imageData) in imageData.enumerated() { multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "imageKey", fileName: "user\(index).jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg") }`? Or the other one? `for (index,imageData) in imageData.enumerated() { multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: \(imageKey)\(index)", fileName: "user.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg") }`?

Comment: then how to upload multiple images to server? i am only able to upload only 1 image (first index of image array). Please share some code i really need help

Comment: When I meant "Can you post multiple images?", I meant: Does the API allows you to upload multiple images at once? What's the doc of that API? We can't guess.

Comment: yes api allow to post multiple images in form of array